# Use link_to to create a new article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use link_to to create a new article and set the article's name.

This is what I've tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Create A New Article called Edward', articles_path, :name =>'Edward', :method => :post %>
```

It creates a new article, but it is blank.

```
<%= link_to 'Create A New Article called Edward', articles_path(:name =>'Edward') , :method => :post %>
```

does exactly the same.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to nest it in an `:articles` hash since your controller is likely trying to access `params[:article]` to get the values (you would think that by putting it within the `articles_path(...)` part this would happen automatically, but it doesn't).

```
articles_path(:article => {:name => "Edward"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to accept answers that work for you, it'll encourage people to answer any future questions you post.